# Tethered shooting with gphoto2 works, but darktable does not find camera

Tags: canon, darktable, linux

I want to use my Canon 1300D and darktable 3.2.1 for my tethered photoshooting. I checked everything with gphoto2 on my Linux Mint Notebook, everything works fine, I can capture photos, but darktable won't recognize my camera, no matter if gphoto2 spawner is running or not. It is not possible to use tethered shooting or regular import

Comment: Have you try with https://entangle-photo.org/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I also had that same darktable 3.8.x tethering situation with the same camera model (1300D) I.e., it tested ok with the gphoto2 command line, etc.

Using a Linux Mint system on a Dell laptop (core-i3 8GB -no added GPU) it worked with the following steps:

1. Be sure to unmount the camera from the file system because when a camera is connected to USB and turned on, it gets mounted to show the list of images in camera storage. Alternatively, remove the card from the camera and set **shoot without card** from Camera → menu.
2. After unmounting the camera, go to darktable and open the **lighttable** panel. If the camera model name displays in the **import** box (at the top left) then choose **mount camera**. A list with **tethered shoot** should appear. Select that.

Tip for the camera freeze problem (which I faced): try not to use the "live view".